# Fetching data from object in API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

```js
function fetch(){
    $.get("https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json", function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
}
```

I want to create a table with api data from the api mentioned above. The data looks something like this:

```json
{
  "State Unassigned": {
    "districtData": {
      "Unassigned": {
        "notes": "",
        "active": 0,
        "confirmed": 0,
        "deceased": 0,
        "recovered": 0,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      }
    },
    "statecode": "UN"
  },
  "Andaman and Nicobar Islands": {
    "districtData": {
      "Nicobars": {
        "notes": "District-wise numbers are out-dated as cumulative counts for each district are not reported in bulletin",
        "active": 0,
        "confirmed": 0,
        "deceased": 0,
        "recovered": 0,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      },
      "North and Middle Andaman": {
        "notes": "District-wise numbers are out-dated as cumulative counts for each district are not reported in bulletin",
        "active": 0,
        "confirmed": 1,
        "deceased": 0,
        "recovered": 1,
        "delta": {
          "confirmed": 0,
          "deceased": 0,
          "recovered": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to know how to fetch data for all such objects.You can also view the code from the mentioned API. I want confirmed,deceased and recovered cases for all objects.
I want table which has district,confirmed,deceased and recovered cases as columns. I know how to get data added up in table. The only thing I don't know is how to fetch data for all objects present there.

Comment: Welcome! The description of your input is clear. However, it is not clear what you want as output. A "table" can be many things. Are you referring to HTML? What did you try to create this table? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Can you share what have you tried yet?

Comment: @trincot I want table which has district,confirmed,deceased and recovered cases as columns.I know how to get data added up in table.The only thing I don't know is how to fetch data for all objects present there.

Comment: You are talking about HTML? Do you know the `table` element? Did you try creating at least a table? This question will be closed soon, because you should really have added very specific information about desired output *in* the question. Just "I want table" is not enough. You should also add your attempts (HTML, JavaScript code).

Comment: You don't need jQuery. See here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-the-javascript-fetch-api-to-get-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, you are looking for populating an HTML table with the data that you get from this web service. As you have tagged your question with `jquery` I suppose you want to use it.

Here is how you could do that:

```js
function populateTable($table) {
    $table.empty().append($("<tr>").append(
        $("<th>").text("state"),
        $("<th>").text("statecode"),
        $("<th>").text("district"),
        $("<th>").text("active"),
        $("<th>").text("confirmed"),
        $("<th>").text("deceased"),
        $("<th>").text("recovered")
    ));
    
    let url = "https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json";
    $.getJSON(url).then(function (data) {
        for (let state in data) {
            let {statecode, districtData} = data[state]
            for (let district in districtData) {
                let { active, confirmed, deceased, recovered } = districtData[district];
                $table.append($("<tr>").append(
                    $("<td>").text(state),
                    $("<td>").text(statecode),
                    $("<td>").text(district),
                    $("<td>").text(active),
                    $("<td>").text(confirmed),
                    $("<td>").text(deceased),
                    $("<td>").text(recovered)
                ));
            }
        }
    });
}

populateTable($("#table"));
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; border: 1px solid }
td, th { border: 1px solid }
td:nth-child(4),
td:nth-child(5),
td:nth-child(6),
td:nth-child(7) { text-align: right }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table"></table>
```

Comment: Can you plz explain the code from getjson part?

Comment: It collects the information from the response (an array), by iterating over it, and iterating over its districtData subarray. Then jQuery is used to append a row to the HTML table.

Comment: Can you explain the iteration once?Like how have you defined object and all

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want me to explain. I have not defined any object.

Comment: Iterating over data means you loop over it, first you get the first array element in the first iteration, then the second in the second iteration. Not sure what you are asking for me?